# MultipartEntityBuilder sends no Post Variables

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to upload a file, alongside some variables to a web service. From what I've read around the net, a MultipartEntityBuilder would be the tool for the job. However, when I use it in the described manner, the post variables (both text and file) don't seem to be sent with the query. The receiving end reacts just as if no post variables were attached.

I've tried testing the theory by pointing the url at a file with the following code:

```
<?php    
$data = "";    
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $data = $data . "Field ".htmlspecialchars($key)." is ".htmlspecialchars($value)."<br>";
}
echo $data;    
?>
```

And the call returned no data (and did return data when I used other methods of posting.

Are there any ideas as to what might be the problem?

```
The code in question:

        String url = "http://aktivthospital.dk.web1.aktivthospital.dk/index.php";

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

        MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        ContentType contentType = ContentType.create(HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE, HTTP.UTF_8);
        entityBuilder.addPart("option", new StringBody("com_redtournament", contentType));
        entityBuilder.addPart("task", new StringBody("competition.apiServiceUploadImage", contentType));
        entityBuilder.addPart("username", new StringBody(_username, contentType));
        entityBuilder.addPart("password", new StringBody(_password, contentType));
        entityBuilder.addPart("comp_id", new StringBody(String.valueOf(_competitionId), contentType));
        entityBuilder.addPart("img_title", new StringBody(_title, contentType));
        File file = new File(_imagepath);
        entityBuilder.addPart("img_file",new FileBody(file));
        httpPost.setEntity(entityBuilder.build());

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: you have a lot of parts. don't you want to use 1 part for url encoded pairs, and 1 for the file ?

Comment: I need to send all the stuff as one call. Otherwise the web service won't know what to do with the file. Is it possible to split it up, and still make is as once call?

Comment: not what I am saying. You are making a multipart with a lot of parts. Usually, there are 2 parts, not 7. 1 with the parameters name value pairs, one with the file.

Comment: Oh.. would you mind making me an answer that shows how that works? That might be my problem.

Comment: It would greatly help me as well. I can either send params with different code, or just a file with similar code you have here. I think I understand what @njzk2 is saying though...

Answer (score 2):

So, I managed to get something to work, I'm not sure if you can do the same but it's worth noting it for others. For background, I was trying to POST to Jenkins.

No matter how hard I tried, I could only add Files to the `MultipartEntityBuilder`. What made it worse (maybe) was that I was too lazy/cocky to change the way I was handling the POST so I had to figure out a way to make it work with as little code change and rewriting as possible.

I tried 
`.addPart(name, new StringBody(value, contentType))` and `.addTextBody(name, value)`

I played around with adding my parameters as a JSON, but that didn't work either. Finally, I remembered when I originally got parameters to work. I eventually decided on something different, but I was able to combine that original success with `MultipartEntityBuilder` for complete success.

If my POST has files, I use `MultipartEntityBuilder` and add those as I have before. For the parameters, however, I add them to the URI. So, for example, what worked for me was this:

http://jenkins.url/.../buildWIthParameters?firstname=firstvalue&secondname=secondvalue

And also set the entity to have the files. The combination of the two worked.

Now, I know we have completely separate, unrelated projects, but I figured it was worth it to document my success, if for no other reason but to give you something else to try.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the worked method (android):

```
 public void post(final String url,
                 final File file,
                 final String fileName,
                 final Map<String, String> params,
                 final FileUploadCallback callback) {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            if (null != params && params.size() > 0) {
                for (String key : params.keySet()) {
                    builder.addTextBody(key, params.get(key), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
                }
            }

            if (null != file && file.exists()) {
                builder.addBinaryBody(fileName, file, ContentType.create("image/jpg"), fileName);
            }

            final HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);

            int statusCode = -1;
            String responseBody;

            try {
                HttpResponse httpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(httpPost);

                StatusLine status = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
                statusCode = status.getStatusCode();
                responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

                if (statusCode >= 300) {
                    sendFailure(callback, statusCode, responseBody, null);
                } else {
                    sendSuccess(callback, statusCode, responseBody);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                sendFailure(callback, statusCode, null, e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: J2EE Java8: `addPart()` doesn't work (as expected), while `addTextBody()` yes (also as expected).